# Make vimdiff ignore unicode equivalence classes

Tags: unicode, equivalent, vimdiff

I try to compare two directories synced by synching. I do this using the following:

```sh
vimdiff <(cd "~/Pictures/shared" && find . | sort) <(ssh argon "cd ~/pictures/shared && find . " | sort)
```

One machine is a recent archlinux box and the local machine is a MacBook Pro. Skimming through the diff I have problems finding real differences because most of the differences are Umlauts that get somehow interpreted wrong:

[image: vimdiff]

Hexdump shows the character differ. Here its a german ö (U+00F6) while there it is a o with combining diaeresis ◌̈ (U+0308). Is vimdiff capable of recognizing these equivalences as identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to translate the encoding before comparing them by piping the output through `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac`:

```sh
vimdiff <(cd ~/Pictures/shared && find . | sort) <(ssh argon "cd ~/pictures/shared && find . " | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac | sort)
```

Also see [this question on iconv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346453/what-the-difference-and-usage-of-encodings-utf-8-and-utf-8-mac-in-iconv).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit each of the buffers to replace the problematic character with the same character in both (eg. here I'd replace them with o). Vimdiff should automatically update after modifying one of the buffers.

For the replacement you can use `:%s/<ctrl+v>u00f6/o/g` (and equiv for the other) the u00f6 should automatically be replaced with the unicode sign in the command line after typing it.